# Changing bootstrap glyphicon based on status

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I have written a ng-grid where the cell background changes color based on the cell data. This is what was working for me

```
cellTemplate: '<div title="{{row.entity.EHStatus.SFT.desc}}" class="ngCellText"'+ 
                                    'ng-class="{\'green\' : row.getProperty(\'EHStatus.SFT.code\') == \'1\' ,\'orange\' : row.getProperty(\'EHStatus.SFT.code\') > \'1\',\'red\' : row.getProperty(\'EHStatus.SFT.code\') == \'0\',\'yellow\' : row.getProperty(\'EHStatus.SFT.code\') < \'0\'}" >&nbsp;</div>'}
```

Now I am trying change the above code so it will use a different bootstrap glyphicon based on the status. Here is my attempt.

```
cellTemplate: '<div  style="text-align:center;" title="{{row.entity.EHStatus.TOPPER.desc}}" class="ngCellText"'+ 
                                    'ng-class="{"glyphicon glyphicon-ok-circle" style="color:green;" : row.getProperty(\'EHStatus.TOPPER.code\') == \'1\' ,...
```

And my styles are below one of them. But obviously my syntax for changing the glyphicon is not right, can someone please help?

```
.green {
    background-color: green;
    color: green;
} ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If your class includes a dash inside the css class name, you must put quotes around it. Example)

```
<div ng-class={glyphicon 'glyphicon-ok': myBooleanStatement}></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way

`<span class="glyphicon green" ng-class="{'glyphicon-ok': {{single_request.status}}==1, 'glyphicon-remove': {{single_request.status}}==0 }" ></span>`

{{single_request.status}}= angular status variable

Answer (score 0):

it is working, you should try this;

`<span class="{{item.Status==true ? 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok':'glyphicon glyphicon-remove'}}" aria-hidden="true"></span>`